# Any form generator(from annotated javabeans) for swing?

Tags: java, swing, entity, form-generator

I've seen several form generators(swing, web etc from javabeans) but cannot find them again.
Help me with links please.

PS generator is not designer, generator - generates ui semi-automatically, no drawing is needed

PPS I have finally found them

- nakedobjects
- jmatter
- metawidget

if you know more please comment

Answer (score 0):

[Swing Form Builder](http://code.google.com/p/swing-formbuilder/)

Answer (score -1):

[JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/)
[Eclipse Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/)
[NetBeans Matisse](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/50/quickstart-gui.html)